# Why can't i print binary tree?

Tags: c++, class, binary-tree

I created a class binary search tree.
but the problem is when i print the tree it crashes.
i think it can be an endless recursion in function print().

Here is my code

```
struct node{
node *l,*r;
int data;
};

class BinTree
{
  private:  node *root;
  public:
   BinTree(){ root=NULL; }
   void add(int a){ add_node(a,root); };
   void add_node(int a, node *rot)
   { node *curr; curr=rot;
       if(curr==NULL)
       {
           curr=new node;
           curr->data=a;
           curr->l=NULL;
           curr->r=NULL;
           return;
       }
       if(a>=curr->data)   curr=curr->r,add_node(a,curr);
       if(a<curr->data)    curr=curr->l,add_node(a,curr);
   }
   void print(){ inorder(root); }
   void inorder(node *curr)
   {
     if(curr->l!=NULL)   inorder(curr->l);
     cout<<curr->data<<" ";
     if(curr->r!=NULL)   inorder(curr->r);
   }
};
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: at least sure to crash when root is NULL

Comment: I see two problems: The first is what makes your programs crash, and it will be obvious if you run the program in a debugger. The other is that you never add nodes to your tree, use a debugger to step through `add_node` to see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `add_node` is broken.  If `curr` is `NULL`, it creates a new node but it never actually adds it to the existing tree.  Thus all additions you make are effectively ignored and the tree stays empty.

The `inorder` function dereferences `curr` without checking whether it is `NULL`, and `print` calls it without checking whether `root` is `NULL`. Thus, your crash most likely is caused by tryin to print out an empty tree and then dereferencing a null pointer.

Answer (score 4):

In your `add_node` method, you never actually assign a value to the root. It should be something like this:

```
if(curr==NULL) 
{ 
    curr=new node; 
    curr->data=a; 
    curr->l=NULL; 
    curr->r=NULL; 
    root = curr;
    return; 
}
```

But, for the future, I have the same advice as Basile - use your compiler and your debugger to your advantange.

Answer (score 2):

Learn **how to use a debugger**. Enable **all warnings in the compiler**.

On Linux, this means compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and debug with `gdb`